# R is torsion free is if and only if the natural map is injective

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, tensor-products

I'm reading Silverman's Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves which has the following statement:

> A ring R is torsion free is equivalent to saying, the map R$\longrightarrow$R$\otimes\mathbb{Q}$ is injective.

Here Silverman considers rings that are complete local rings.I know the statement is true if R is a domain but is it true in general and does complete local imply that R is a domain?

Comment: The multiplication in $R$ is not needed at all. It only needs to be an abelian group (or a $D$-module for a general integral domain $D$ where $\mathbb{Q}$ is replaced with the field of fractions of $D$ and the tensor product is taken over $D$).

Comment: Ok I think I misunderstood the statement. Considering R as a Z module should suffice. Thanks.